# ScrollView kivy

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

I have Python code:

```py
class Screen3(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.scv = ScrollView()
        self.bl_main = BoxLayout()
        self.bl_main.padding = [20, 20, 20, 20]
        self.bl_main.spacing = 50
        self.bl_main.orientation = 'vertical'
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        for i in [f'Button {i+1}' for i in range(20)]:
            b = Button()
            b.size_hint = None, None
            b.size = 350, 350
            b.text = i
            anch = AnchorLayout()
            anch.anchor_x = 'right'
            anch.add_widget(b)
            self.bl_main.add_widget(anch)
        self.scv.add_widget(self.bl_main)
        self.add_widget(self.scv)
```

And I have `kivy` code:

```
Screen3:
    name: 'screen3'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: vertical
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            MDToolbar:
                title: "History"
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()], ['skip-backward', lambda x: app.change_screen('main screen', screen_manager)]]
                elevation: 12
```

Here you can see my app.
https://pasteboard.co/J7KTdeR.jpg

1. Why i can't click on my icon-buttons?
2. Why my paddings and spacings don't consider and why ScrollView widget doesn't work?

How do I correct both of these points?

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your icon-Buttons don't work because the `ScrollView` that you add in `on_enter()` has the default `size_hint` of (1,1), and thus fills the entire `Screen3` (even though parts of the `ScrollView` are transparent). The `ScrollView` is grabbing the mouse clicks, so the icon-Buttons never see the mouse clicks.

In a similar way, the `BoxLayout` (bl_main) also has the default `size_hint`, so its height will be the height of the `ScrollView`, and it will try to fit the 20 `Buttons` in that `height`. Each `Button` gets its share of the height, which is not enough, so they overlap.

The fix is to build the `ScrollView` and `BoxLayout` in the `kv` to take advantage of the automatic bindings, and to set their sizes. Here is a version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class Screen3(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        for i in [f'Button {i+1}' for i in range(20)]:
            b = Button()
            b.size_hint = None, None
            b.size = 350, 350
            b.text = i
            # anch = AnchorLayout()
            # anch.anchor_x = 'right'
            # anch.add_widget(b)
            # self.ids.bl_main.add_widget(anch)
            self.ids.bl_main.add_widget(b)


kv = '''
Screen3:
    name: 'screen3'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: toolbar.height
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':1}
        # AnchorLayout:
        #     anchor_x: 'center'
        #     anchor_y: 'top'
        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: "History"
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()], ['skip-backward', lambda x: app.change_screen('main screen', screen_manager)]]
            elevation: 12
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (None, None)
        height: root.height - toolbar.height
        width: 390  # Button width plus BoxLayout padding
        pos_hint: {'right':1}
        BoxLayout:
            id: bl_main
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            padding: [20, 20, 20, 20]
            spacing: 50
'''


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_string(kv))
        return sm


TestApp().run()
```

Note the setting of sizes, positions, and the use of `height: self.minimum_height` for the `BoxLayout`. Refer to the [ScrollView documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#managing-the-content-size-and-position) for the reasoning behind this.

I have also commented out your use of `AnchorLayout`, as it is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks so much, code works!

What is it self.minimum_height?
I did not found him in documentation.

Comment: The `minimum_height` (and `minimum_width`) are attributes of some `Layouts` (like [BoxLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html#kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout.minimum_height) and [GirdLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout.minimum_height) ). For these values to be calculated correctly, you must set heights for the children (`size_hint` won't work). This is ideal for use in a `ScrollView` child.